# Android MonthView,WeekView and DayView

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create a calendar app containing MonthView, WeekView and DayView functionality.I have searched a lot but still can't find proper sample. Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

[Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

I hope this can help you.I think it includes all what you need and is designed very cool.

[image]